# Hard time writing a simple code on jscript

Tags: jscript

I have hard time with this simple jscript for no reason. this code should display the time once clicked. but i get the error below. what am i doing wrong

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 30,
  "colno": 43
}
```

```js
function item(name)
{

 var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("but1").innerHTML = d;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script src="C:\Users\kalyanasundar.s\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Desktop\proj\animation\index.Js"></script>

<h2>JavaScript Statements</h2>

<p id="demo">You cannot break a code line with a \ backslash.</p>
<button onclick="item(name)">Try it</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML element with `ID="but1"`?

Comment: That seemed to have resolved it. Not sure why i make sleazy mistakes :-)

Answer (score 1):

This id (#but1) does not exist, so innerHtml won't work, try changing it.

```js
function item(name) {

  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script src="C:\Users\kalyanasundar.s\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Desktop\proj\animation\index.Js"></script>

  <h2>JavaScript Statements</h2>

  <p id="demo">You cannot break a code line with a \ backslash.</p>
  <button onclick="item(name)">Try it</button>



</body>

</html>
```